# Best way to convert uint64_t to jlong

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, uint64

I am writing a JNI code and encounter a situation where I will need convert uint64_t to jlong, and here's my current way to convert uint64_t to jlong:

```
jlong uint64_t_to_jlong (uint64_t value) {
  if (value > std::numeric_limits<jlong>::max()) {
    return std::numeric_limits<jlong>::max(); 
  }
  return static_cast<jlong>(value);
}
```

And this is obviously not a perfect approach as it can't really convert the value correctly when `value > std::numeric_limits<jlong>::max()`.  However, directly returning `static_cast<jlong>(value)` doesn't sound a good approach to me either, as in the Java side we will receive negative value.

Can I know whether there exist better approach which can handle all cases smoothly and correctly?

Comment: What do you want to happen when the value is greater than 2^63?  Your only options are cast to the corresponding negative value or throw an exception, since Java doesn't have an unsigned 64-bit primitive integer type.

Comment: So is there any standard way to convert such negative value in the Java side? I am worried about whether it is platform specific stuff or not.

Comment: Java code can treat a signed long as unsigned, but you have to be careful about it.

Comment: @LouisWasserman: Can I know more about the process of treating a signed long as unsigned in Java? esp. for 64-bit int.

Comment: Addition, subtraction, and multiplication are the same for signed and unsigned values; it's only division, remainder, comparison, and string conversion which you have to worry about.  Java 8 provides libraries to do those for you, failing that you could use Guava's [unsigned libraries](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/UnsignedLongs.html) or reimplement them yourself.

Comment: Can you point me which Java 8 function can to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comment by Louis, one way to handle it in Java 8 is to simply cast `uint64_t` to `jlong` in the C++ side, then use the set of unsigned operation provided by Java 8 such as [Long.compareUnsigned()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#compareUnsigned-long-long-) to do the necessary operation:

```
public static int compareUnsigned(long x, long y)
Compares two long values numerically treating the values as unsigned.
```

Google Guava's [unsigned libraries](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/primitives/UnsignedLongs.html) can also achieve this in case Java 8 is not used.